# .htaccess QSA flag overridden by $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my rewrite rule

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]`

When I go to this url

`http://localhost/ub/ab?uri=cd`

`$_GET['uri']` returns `cd`, instead `ab`.

How to get `$_GET['uri']` returns `ab`? Or is this the real behavior of QSA?

thanks,

**EDIT**

the `.htaccess` file is in `ub` directory, `ab` directory is never exist.

Comment: URI is actually `/ub/ab` so RewriteRule can be modified to attend query parameter `ub/ab`. Will that be enough or do you want to return last part of URI i.e. ab only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use $_GET to to retrieve the uri parameter - .htaccess rules don't override the URI that's presented to your script, so you can retrieve the "ab" portion of the URI by parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

I've seen several PHP applications - such as Joomla! and Magento - whose .htaccess files simply redirect everything to "index.php", and leave it to the PHP routing code to translate the URI into a page to display.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$_GET['uri']` is realy `cd` due to `?uri=cd`. `ab` is a part of URL, not a part of GET query.

I think this happen because you've defined `uri=` GET query parameter in both `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]` and in address you access (`http://localhost/ub/ab?uri=cd`). It's overridden by second one.

Look:

1. You access `http://localhost/ub/ab?uri=cd` (query string is `?uri=cd`)
2. mod_rewrite send it to `index.php` and appends URL to it in `uri` GET parameter ( > `index.php?uri=ub/ab`)
3. Then mod_rewrite (due to `QSA`) Appends Query String, so we get `index.php?uri=ub/ab&uri=cd`

So `uri=` placed twice in final request and is overridden by second one.

Just rename one of your GET `uri` parameters.

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to mention, that .htaccess file is in `ub` drectory, ab is not a directory

Comment: ya, i got it, but now i prefer to to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` like Brilliand answer. The standard is better thought.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have your RewriteRule like this to ignore/overwrite prior Query String:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```